# Magento API SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '[url]/index.php/api/index/index/?wsdl=1' : Couldn't find end of Start Tag part line 56

Tags: api, magento

When I go to [url]/api (where [url] is the url of my Magento), I get this response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
<faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.example.com/magento/1.7/index.php/api/index/index/?wsdl=1' : Couldn't find end of Start Tag part line 56
</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The correct response should be:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>Sender</faultcode>
<faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What gives ?

Comment: What do you mean what gives?  What makes you think the response should be the later?

Comment: Well Alan, two things make me think that the response should be the later.  
If you load the base Mage_Api URL

http://magento.example.com/api

directly in a browser, you’ll get a response something like this

 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>Sender</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

which looks a bit like a SOAP response.

Comment: With the exception of the first sentence, my previous post contains a quotation of your 4th article about the Magento API.  This was the first thing.  The second thing is: On the "official" Magento demo site, appending "api" to the home page url gives the same response "Sender/Invalid XML"

Comment: My installation is a basic install, with the demo data loaded.  Appending "api/soap/index?wsdl" to the url displays the WSDL XML.  My question is: why do I receive an incorrect response ?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to load the WSDL yourself from the mentioned URL? http://www.example.com/magento/1.7/index.php/api/index/index/?wsdl=1

Comment: It displays the WSDL XML in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late but hope my reply will be useful for someone in future.

I had exactly the same problem. I had installed Zend Server (PHP 5.3.9) and was getting the same error. I searched a lot and applied all available solutions but fails.... Finally, i installed wamp and then run 'Soap Client' script over there and it runs successfully.

Then i reached on this point that Zend Server (PHP 5.3.9) has some default bug in 'Soap Client' Script. I uninstalled Zend Server (PHP 5.3.9) and installed Zend Server (PHP 5.4.11) and runs 'Soap Client' script over there. This time it runs successfully.

Conclusion: Please use latest PHP version (Zend Server) or (Wamp Server) as, there is default 'Soap Client' bug in some PHP versions, one i mentioned above.

Thanks, Kashif

Answer (score -1):

The answer is: it comes from a PHP bug.  The truth is in a post by floriancarstens here: [Magento Forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/56528/)